# How to change Openshift jenkins java version?

Tags: openshift

Does anybody know how to build with Java 7 on Openshift jenkins?

I'm getting this?
(from jenkins output)

```
.........
Maven home: /etc/alternatives/maven-3.0
Java version: 1.6.0_30, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre
.........
.........
[ERROR] javac: invalid target release: 1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins GUI has the option of downloading a customer JDK. You should use that to auto-install.

Comment: Not on Openshift, have you specifically done this on Openshift?

Comment: More on this, I configured jenkins to install java7 but now blocked by this same issue https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/unable-to-download-jdk-for-jenkins-maven-job

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're looking for.  When you deploy jenkins on openshift, you're essentially getting your own standalone instance.  You can go in to configure to download new JDKs, e.g. JDK 7.  This is on the configure screen.  Yes I've done this on OpenShift.

Comment: Trying to add jdk 7 from Manage Jenkins, to no avail.... Getting a BindException while trying to download/install jdk. So in short, you could be right but I haven't got that far to be able to install/pick the jdk to build on the job config screen. Instead I added an environment variable for JAVA_HOME pointing to jdk7.  And that's how solved the issue....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by ssh'ing into the jenkins cloud instance, then using wget to download the jdk tar.gz and unzipped it into the ~/app-data/dependencies folder